# Brush by default active on scatter chart

Tags: echarts

Is there any Option for active brush without showing a toolbox.

Working with Echarts library version 3 . trying to find a solution with Echarts provided Document
"https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#toolbox.feature.brush.icon.rect"

Sample Code

```js
{
  brush: {
    toolbox: ['rect'],
    brushLink: [0, 1, 2, 3],
    brushType: 'rect',
    brushMode: ['single'],
    outOfBrush: {
      color: '#abc'
    },
    brushStyle: {
      borderWidth: 2,
      color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
    },
    throttleDelay: 300
  },
  toolbox: {
    show: false,
    feature: {
      brush: {
        type: ['rect'],
        title: {
          rect: 'Active Brush'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since not many people on SO use Echarts, I always ask the devs directly at https://github.com/ecomfe/echarts/issues. Just open an issue in English, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 3):

To enable dataZoom feature (pragmatically) in echarts toolbar I have used below method

```
echartInstance._componentsMap[Object.keys(echartInstance._componentsMap)[0]]._features['dataZoom'].model.iconPaths.zoom.trigger('click');
```

or

```
echartInstance._componentsMap[' - 0_toolbox']._features['dataZoom'].model.iconPaths.zoom.trigger('click');
```

Similarly you can enable any echarts toolbar feature using the same mechanism.

**Note:** If you are using latest EChart then you may have to use _componentsViews instead of _componentsMap.

Thanks to Rob Laverty for updating us for above change.

Comment: With the latest, you'll want to use `_componentsViews` instead of `_componentsMap `

Answer (score 1):

Just did this to Echarts 5:

```
echartInstance._componentsViews
.find(c => c._features && c._features.dataZoom) 
._features.dataZoom.model.iconPaths.zoom.trigger('click')
```